# SQL Server query for finding weeknumber of a month considering thursday as week counter

Tags: sql-server, week-number

I need a week number of the month. The week needs to start on Thursday.

I have tried many answers but i the below conditions are not satifying it.

For example: the week number for the below date is

```
SL  Date        Weeknumber   
---------------------------
1) 21/09/2017 - 3
2) 28/09/2017 - 4
3) 23/03/2017 - 4
4) 29/06/2017 - 5
5) 15/03/2018 - 3
6) 28/03/2018 - 4
7) 29/03/2018 - 5
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @DhruvJoshi EOmonth key word is not working in 2008 server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for. Kind of crazy, I know, but it works:

```
create table #months (date date);

insert into #months
values ('20170921')
    , ('20170928')
    , ('20170323')
    , ('20170629')
    , ('20180315')
    , ('20180328')
    , ('20180329');

select date
    , case 
        when weeksdif * 7 <= daysdiff
            then weeksdif + 1
        else weeksdif
        end [week nr]
from (
    select *
        , wk - wk_startOfMonth [weeksdif]
        , DATEDIFF(DAY, startOfMonth, date) [daysdiff]
    from (
        select *
            , DATEPART(wk, startOfMonth) wk_startOfMonth
            , DATEPART(WEEKDAY, startOfMonth) wkd_startOfMonth
        from (
            select *
                , DATEPART(wk, date) wk
                , DATEPART(weekday, date) wkd
                , cast( (CAST(YEAR(date) as varchar(8)) 
                        + RIGHT('0' + CAST(month(date) as varchar(8)), 2) 
                        + '01') as date) startOfMonth
            from #months
            ) result_set
        ) result_set
    ) result_set
order by date;
```

Comment: Sorry . It is working fine all months except for month starting on thursday. For Example 29/06/2017, 15/03/2018, 28/03/2018 it is giving wrong values

Comment: @newjenn So you would be expecting 5, 3, 5?

Comment: I am expecting the answer .  29/06/2017 - 5  , 15/03/2018 - 3 , 28/03/2018 -4 , 29/03/2018 -5

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: @newjenn If this has worked for you please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input table is like

```
TableOfDates([SL] int,[Date] date)
```

Following query will give correct weeknumbers

```
set datefirst 4
go

--create table TableOfDates([SL] int,[Date] datetime)
--insert into TableOfDates values 
--(1,'09-21-2017'),
--(2,'09-28-2017'),
--(3,'03-23-2017')

select 

    t.Date,DATEPART(wk,t.[Date])- DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(d,1,DATEADD(m,-1,EOMONTH(t.[Date]))))
from TableOfDates t

go
--drop table TableOfDates
set datefirst 7
go
```

**For SQL SERVER 2008 version**

you can use following query

```
select 

    t.Date,DATEPART(wk,t.[Date])- DATEPART(wk,cast(dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,t.date),0) as date))
from TableOfDates t
```

**Explanation**

Set Datefirst by default is set to 7. We direct SQL server to use thursday(4) as the start of week.
See [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) on this.

now since weeknumbers are calculated from the start of the year, and we need monthly weeknumbers, we calculate weeknumbers for the current date and the start of the month and their difference gives monthly weeknumbers

In the end we set back the datefirst to the default value of 7

**See attached output**

[image]

Comment: EOMONTH key word is not working in 2008 server. It seems it is working in 2012 server

Comment: It is not working for a scenario when month starting on thursday.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATAFIRST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

From MSDN:-

> Sets the first day of the week to a number from 1 through 7.

```
╔═══════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║           Value           ║ First day of the week is ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ 1                         ║ Monday                   ║
║ 2                         ║ Tuesday                  ║
║ 3                         ║ Wednesday                ║
║ 4                         ║ Thursday                 ║
║ 5                         ║ Friday                   ║
║ 6                         ║ Saturday                 ║
║ 7 (default, U.S. English) ║ Sunday                   ║
╚═══════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

so use the next code:-

```
Set DATEFIRST 4
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2017-09-21'

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, @DATE)  -
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,@DATE), 0)) AS WEEK_OF_MONTH
```

**Result:-**

```
3
```

Comment: your logic is working fine for all conditions except for the month starting on thursday. Example                                                                          Date              WEEK_OF_MONTH
15/03/2018 2
28/03/2018 3
29/06/2017 4
28/06/2017 3
15/06/2017 2